I'm trying to deploy this contract but it fails
Here is the error:

Here is my code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";



contract Wenmarket {
    address payable investorReceiver;
    address payable receiver005; //this is my address, temp
    address payable receiver095;
    uint256 public percentage005 = 5;
    uint256 public percentage095 = 95;
    uint256 public OPtokenInvested;
    ERC20 public customerToken; //temp

    constructor(address payable _investorReceiver,
    address payable _receiver005,
    address payable _receiver095,
    uint256 _percentage005,
    uint256 _percentage095,
    ERC20 _customerToken) {
        require((percentage005 + percentage095) == 100, "Must equal 100")
        ;investorReceiver = _investorReceiver
        ;receiver005 = _receiver005
        ;receiver095 = _receiver095
        ;percentage005 = _percentage005
        ;percentage095 = _percentage095
        ;customerToken = _customerToken; //project fundraising
    }

        uint256 amount005 = ((msg.value * percentage005) / 100);
        uint256 amount095 = ((msg.value * percentage095) / 100);


    // for frontend
    event AmountInvestedAddedToTotalInvested(uint256 amount);

    function sendViaCall(address payable _to) public payable {
        // Call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
        // This is the current recommended method to use.
        (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value: amount005}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    function sendViaCall2(address payable _to) public payable {
        // Call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
        // This is the current recommended method to use.
        (bool sent, ) = _to.call{value: amount095}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    function distribute() public payable {
        investorReceiver = payable(CALLER);

        uint256 tokenAmount = msg.value; // temp declaration -> rate

        customerToken.transferFrom(CALLER, investorReceiver, tokenAmount); //send project's tokens to person helping with funding, this takes into account the fact that our wallet will already have all tokens needed for the crowdfunding, hence CALLER

        sendViaCall(receiver005);
        sendViaCall(receiver095);

        emit AmountInvestedAddedToTotalInvested(OPtokenInvested);

    }

}

This is coded using the Optimsim L2 ethereum stack (which is why I'm using CALLER instead of msg.sender).
When testing I use the Ethereum token contract for both addresses required since I don't have any other testnet tokens, maybe I'm missing something important, I've looked at it a couple of times and can't seem to find why it's failing.

Can you share the constructor arguments that you're passing while deploying your contract? Please add the same in your question.
